# How do I find the set of regions that are fully enclosed by a color?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tiles

How do I get all areas surrounded by a certain color in a multidimensional array?

For example, this map has three regions that are fully enclosed by *red* tiles. They are highlighted enclosed in pink.

[image]

I'd want the algorithm to return three regions, with the positions of the tiles inside them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
iterate your whole playing field to create a list of all non-red tiles called LIST
while LIST has entries
    flood-fill from the first entry of LIST
    remove the results of the flood-fill from LIST
    if no result of the flood-fill is at the edge of the map
        add floodfill result to surrounded areas
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a great solution, but how would i do the "flood-fill from the first entry of LIST" ?

Comment: I assumed you already know how flood-fill works. Do you need an explanation of the flood-fill algorithm? Or do you want to know how to get the first element of an array in Javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure how i would do the flood-fill and return the results to check if they're at the edge of the map.

Comment: A tile is at the edge of the map when its x- or y-coordinate is either 0 or maximum. To return a list of results from a flood-fill, you need to pass said list between recursive calls and add any newly visited tile to it.

Comment: @AndriesvandenBerg An answer would be too long for a comment. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking, for every non-red, border tile, flood red. At last the non-red tiles are surrounded by red.

In the example starting from top-left corner going anti-clockwise...

[image]